# Element Binding in Element Binding in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, element-binding

I'm using element binding in XML to get data from an OData service in the controller:

```
{myModel2>/oData/ProdOrdSet('123456789')/Gmein}
```

The whole thing should now work with dynamic numbers instead of `123456789`.
I started with the following approach:

```
{myModel2>/oData/ProdOrdSet('{myModelLD>/Aufnr}')/Gmein}
```

So another JSON Model and another element in the first. Unfortunately this did not work, kindly help?

Comment: Try using {myModel2>/oData/ProdOrdSet('{= ${myModelLD>/Aufnr}}')/Gmein} (not tested, see expression binding in the SAP documentation)

Comment: Do you only want to show exactly one entry? Or do you want to use this binding as a part of an aggregation binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the ID in a local variable and form the binding path to bind. Instead of this

```
{myModel2>/oData/ProdOrdSet('{myModelLD>/Aufnr}')/Gmein}
```

try binding as below:

```
var id = getModel("myModelLD").getProperty("/Aufnr");
var sPath = "myModel2>/oData/ProdOrdSet('"+id+"')/Gmein";
this.getView().bindElement(sPath);
```